# Angular 6 registration form not sending

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular

I'm doing a project an asp.net angular 6 project and am trying to include a registration and login form. So far my login form is working but my registration form isn't doing anything when pressing the register button. I'm following the same logic from my login form, I was wondering if anyone could point out to me why it isn't working.

register.component.html

```
<div class="container card" style="width:40rem;">
  <div class="row justify-content-center card-header bg-primary" >
    <div class="col">
      <h2 class="text-center text-white mb-4">Register</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center card-body mt-2">
    <div class="col-6">
      <form (ngSubmit)="onRegister()" [formGroup]="registerForm">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col">
            <label>
              First name
              <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="firstName"/>
            </label>
            <span class="help-block text-danger" *ngIf="registerForm.get('firstName').touched && registerForm.get('firstName').invalid">First name is required.</span>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col">
            <label>
              Last name
              <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="lastName"/>
            </label>
            <span class="help-block text-danger" *ngIf="registerForm.get('lastName').touched && registerForm.get('lastName').invalid">Last name is required.</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col">
            <label>
              Address
              <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="address"/>
            </label>
            <span class="help-block text-danger" *ngIf="registerForm.get('address').touched && registerForm.get('address').invalid">Address is required.</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col">
            <label>
              E-mail
              <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email"/>
            </label>
            <span class="help-block text-danger" *ngIf="registerForm.get('email').touched && registerForm.get('email').invalid">Email is required and must be a valid email address.</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col">
            <label>
              Date of Birth
              <input type="date" class="form-control" formControlName="dateOfBirth"/>
            </label>
            <span class="help-block text-danger" *ngIf="registerForm.get('dateOfBirth').touched && registerForm.get('dateOfBirth').invalid">Date of birth is required.</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col">
            <label>
              Password
              <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password"/>
            </label>
              <span class="help-block text-danger" *ngIf="registerForm.get('password').touched && registerForm.get('password').invalid">
                <span *ngIf="registerForm.get('password').errors['passwordComplexity']" class="help-block d-block">The password needs to start with a letter and contain a number and a special character.</span>
                <span *ngIf="registerForm.get('password').errors['passwordLength']" class="help-block d-block">The password must be at least 8 characters long.</span>
              </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col">
            <label>
              Security question
              <select class="form-control" formControlName="securityQuestion">
                <option *ngFor="let question of securityQuestions" value="{{question.id}}">{{question.question}}</option>
              </select>
            </label>
            <span class="help-block text-danger" *ngIf="registerForm.get('securityQuestion').touched && registerForm.get('securityQuestion').invalid">Answer to security question is required</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col">
            <label>
              Answer to security question
              <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="securityAnswer"/>
            </label>
            <span class="help-block text-danger" *ngIf="registerForm.get('securityAnswer').touched && registerForm.get('securityAnswer').invalid">Answer to security question is required</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col text-right">
            <button  class="btn btn-primary mr-2" [disabled]="registerForm.invalid">
              Sign up
            </button>
            <a class="mr-2" [routerLink]="['/account']">
              <button class="btn btn-warning">
                Cancel
              </button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

register.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
import {MessageService} from "../../services/message.service";
import {ApiMethod, ApiService} from "../../services/api.service";
import {PasswordValidator} from "../../shared/validators/password.validator";
import {User, UserUpdateResult} from "../../shared/user-model";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {SecurityQuestion} from "../../shared/security.question.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit{
  public securityQuestions: SecurityQuestion[] = [];
  public registerForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
    lastName: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
    address: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
    email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.email, Validators.required]),
    dateOfBirth: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
    password: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, PasswordValidator.Length, PasswordValidator.Complexity]),
    securityQuestion: new FormControl(1, Validators.required),
    securityAnswer: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
  });

  constructor(public messageService: MessageService,
              public apiService: ApiService,
              public httpClient: HttpClient){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.httpClient.get(this.apiService.getUrl(ApiMethod.GetSecurityQuestions)).subscribe((questions: SecurityQuestion[]) => {
      this.securityQuestions = questions;
    })
  }

  public onRegister(){
    const user = new User();

    user.fullName = this.registerForm.value.firstName + ' ' + this.registerForm.value.lastName;
    user.password = this.registerForm.value.password;
    user.email = this.registerForm.value.email;
    user.address = this.registerForm.value.address;
    user.dateOfBirth = new Date(this.registerForm.value.dateOfBirth);

    const securityQuestion = new SecurityQuestion();
    securityQuestion.id = this.registerForm.value.securityQuestion;
    securityQuestion.answer = this.registerForm.value.securityAnswer;
    user.securityQuestion = securityQuestion;

    this.httpClient.post(this.apiService.getUrl(ApiMethod.UserSelfRegister), user).subscribe((result: UserUpdateResult) => {
      if(result == UserUpdateResult.UsernameTaken){
        this.messageService.error('User cannot be created', 'This user is already registered.');
        return;
      }
      this.messageService.success('User registered', 'Waiting for activation. Please check your inbox for an email once your account has been activated.');
      this.registerForm.reset();
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `type="submit"` in `button` tag

```
<button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-2" [disabled]="registerForm.invalid">
     Sign up
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `type="submit"` to your `button` tag or you can remove `(ngSubmit)="onRegister()"` from your `form` tag and add `(click)="onRegister()"` to your `button` tag.